# ec2 aws describe-volumes giving HTTPSConnectionPool error

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backup

This one has me a little puzzled, so I figured it might be worth posting here.

I'm trying to take regular snapshots of an Amazon EC2 instance for the sake of making backups.  Thankfully, some very smart people have already written a rather nice shell script that does this: https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup

The idea behind this is that it uses the Amazon AWS CLI tools to call in to Amazon and trigger a snapshot of a given volume.  In theory, this works great, however I've run into a bit of a strange problem.

The script above makes the following call:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes
```

This is supposed to return a list of the Amazon volumes.  However, it is failing with the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ec2.us-west2a.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Cuased by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

I understand why it is throwing this error: the ec2.us-west2a.amazonaws.com endpoint isn't a valid endpoint.  It should be ec2.us-west2.amazonaws.com (without the "a" after "west2").  Despite poking around in the shell script, I can't for the life of me figure out where the aws ec2 describe-volumes call is actually getting the endpoint from.  If I run the command:

```
ec2-describe-volumes
```

I get a valid list of volumes, including the one I'm trying to back up.  In my ~/.profile, I have properly set my EC2_URL, EC2_REGION environment variables and made sure to reload them, but am still getting the above error.

Can anyone tell me where "aws ec2 describe-volumes" is actually getting the endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Given the listing above showing you the region names, you can use the --region parameter to override where the script is automatically finding the region info.  For example:
"aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id vol-xxxxxxxx --region us-west-2"

I was having the same issue while trying to create the snapshot (as you see above) and once I got the region name right from the list previously posted, this worked just fine.

Best of luck!

Comment: elaborate more on your answer, don't leave it this abstract

Answer (score 0):

It's `ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstood my question.  I don't need to know the endpoint - I already know what the correct endpoint should look like.  What I'm after is how that endpoint is actually being set - where does the "aws ec2 describe-volumes" pull the endpoint from?  An environment variable? Out of thin air?